# My Tumblr blog keeps returning "This webpage is not available"

Tags: tumblr, error

I have a tumblr blog at http://blog.amir.rachum.com/
About 50% of the times I enter it, I get a `This webpage is not available` error. Other stuff I host myself in other subdomains, etc., work perfectly. When I get this error I have to hit refresh several (2-4) times until I get the page.
Any idea what could be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: link works for me. You could be the victim of not waiting long enough for the DNS to propogate after setting it up. You should also try flushing your DNS cache if you hit this problem.  Commenting because there's not really an "Answer" for this one since the problem isn't really a problem.

Comment: @Dez it's been at least a month since I set it up, and it happens to me all the time. I also get complaints from readers about this.

Comment: Hmm... maybe this is better for the webmasters group since it involves webpage not available and a custom tumblr domain name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried contacting Tumblr with your username then contacting your vendor that you bought the domain from? Could be a server related issue on Tumblr's side, same thing happens with Twitter occasionally.

Comment: Forgot to come back and answer this one. I contacted Tumblr and it turns out it was some sort of CNAME error on my side. Anyway, since you suggested contacting them, I'm gonna mark your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I found that I did not have proper DNS redirection for my subdomain. Go to the settings for your hosting provider and make sure the DNS for the subdomain includes a CNAME redirection to `domains.tumblr.com`.